# Determining what perspectives/views are being loaded into workspace from Eclipse workspace.xmi

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse Mars.1 RCP

I am trying to determine a way of knowing what views are being populated from the workspace.xmi upon re-opening of my program. In particular:

```
"org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView".
```

My reason for this is the program I am working on uses a custom(somewhat?) console that is invoked by going into a "help" tab and clicking a "show console" button that executes a showConsole() function that opens the view and begins logging of errors or displaying stored errors.

The problem I'm having is that upon closing the workspace and re-opening it the view is created however the console shows "there is not console to display at this time" until you go back into the help tab and click show console which executes that logging function. I need a way of determining if that view is being created on startup so I can then start the logging automatically.

Has anyone ever done something like this before or know if it's possible without writing some huge parser to parse the .xmi looking for that plugin on startup?

Comment: You could just call IWorbenchPage 'findView' to find the view once the UI is initialized.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure when it is that the UI is finished initializing. Is there a way to check?

Comment: The UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE event is fired when startup is complete

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this but I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @greg-449 from what he describes it seems to me that he needs to extend `org.eclipse.ui.startup` and add a handler to execute a part of the tasks that his `show console` button do or am I wrong?

Comment: @JohnDoe org.eclipse.ui.startup runs before the UI has finished starting. Doing a `Display.asyncExec` from there usually delays things enough